# Attempting to make a repeat function in java that will repeat a function 'x' times and will then proceed to load another function after 'x' times

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on trying to create a random image generator that will show a random image in Javascript. I've been able to make it show a random image via the Javascript math and using random variables. But sadly I'm still yet to be eligible to make my code repeat itself.

I know its probably very simplistic but as you know, we all start from somewhere. I've tried my best to compact my code and I have looked at other stackoverflow recourses but im still in no luck.

A quick overview of what happens, you are meant to be able to press a button and then, a selected random image is replaced by the current one.

**What I want:** to be able to press a button and then it will proceed to cycle through the random images 'x' times.

My code:

```js
function imgRandom() {
  var myImages1 = new Array();
  myImages1[1] = "images/Random/Icon1.png";
  myImages1[2] = "images/Random/Icon2.png";
  myImages1[3] = "images/Random/Icon3.png";
  myImages1[4] = "images/Random/Icon4.png";
  myImages1[5] = "images/Random/Icon5.png";
  myImages1[6] = "images/Random/Icon6.png";
  myImages1[7] = "images/Random/Icon7.png";
  myImages1[8] = "images/Random/Icon8.png";
  myImages1[9] = "images/Random/Icon9.png";
  myImages1[10] = "images/Random/Icon10.png";
  myImages1[11] = "images/Random/Icon11.png";
  myImages1[12] = "images/Random/Icon12.png";
  myImages1[13] = "images/Random/Icon13.png";
  myImages1[14] = "images/Random/Icon14.png";
  myImages1[15] = "images/Random/Icon15.png";
  myImages1[16] = "images/Random/Icon16.png";
  myImages1[17] = "images/Random/Icon17.png";
  myImages1[18] = "images/Random/Icon18.png";
  myImages1[19] = "images/Random/Icon19.png";
  myImages1[20] = "images/Random/Icon20.png";
  myImages1[21] = "images/Random/Icon21.png";
  myImages1[22] = "images/Random/Icon22.png";
  myImages1[23] = "images/Random/Icon23.png";
  var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * myImages1.length);
  if (rnd == 0) {
    rnd = 1;
  }

  document.getElementById("gen-img").src = myImages1[rnd];
}
```

```html
<center>
  <p>
    <img id="gen-img" class="character-image" src="images/QuestionMark.png" style="width:180px;height:310px;">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Choose" onclick="setTimeout(imgRandom, 3000);" />
  </p>
</center>
```

I hope this isn't too confusing, i'll be active for a long time if you're able to help! Thanks,
David.

Comment: java != javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored your code a bit with an possible approach Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/d2py2jvb/

I commented with some explanations.

```
/* some flags you can set */
var timesTocycle = 10;
var totalImagesToCreate = 23;
var timeBetweenCycle = 3000;

/* global variables */
var allMyImages = [];
var timesCycled = 0;

/* 
    function to create your images path. 
  Called once when you load your page.
*/
function createMyImages(total) {
  for (var i=0; i<total;i++) {
    var imageNumber = i+1;
    var path = getImagePath(imageNumber);
    allMyImages.push(path);
  }
}

/* separated your path getter */
function getImagePath(imageNumber) {
    return "images/Random/Icon" + imageNumber + ".png";
}

/* this is the function called when you press the button and when one cycle ends */
function triggerRandomImage() {
  if (timesCycled >= timesTocycle) return;
  setTimeout(displayRandomImage, timeBetweenCycle);
}

/* random integer javascript function */
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

}

/* function called on setTimeout */
function displayRandomImage() {

  var rnd = getRandomInt(0,allMyImages.length-1);
  var imageToDisplayPath = allMyImages[rnd];
    document.getElementById("gen-img").src = imageToDisplayPath;
  timesCycled++;
  triggerRandomImage();

  /* debug info */
  document.getElementById('info').innerText = "(showing: " + imageToDisplayPath + ", cycle: " + timesCycled + ", max: " + timesTocycle + ")";
}


/* call this function to populate the allMyImages array */
createMyImages(totalImagesToCreate);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your awesome reply!, May I ask where I would put the list of my images?

Comment: you're welcome. It's bein generated in the `createMyImages` method. This function populates `allMyImages` array with your path sequence: *images/Random/Icon1.png*, *images/Random/Icon2.png*, *images/Random/Icon3.png*...

Comment: Hi mrlew, thank you seriously so much for your kind effort in helping me, I understand you're probably way more advanced than me and its nice to see your generosity. I have one final question, is there anyway to be able to repeat the button? Because once it is clicked you would need to refresh the code to be eligible to do it again, Seriously thank you so much. - David

Comment: No problem, @BeastFox, but you mean after all cycles are complete?

Comment: Correct, after you click the button @MrLew after all cyclers are complete you need to refresh the page to use the button for an output again.

Comment: I updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/d2py2jvb/8/ with a status control. So, you can cycle again. But it's just an approach. I strongly suggest you to learn what the code is doing so you can perform further modifications/improvements. Another thing: It's not a good idea to declare global variables like that. You can search for the module pattern (IIFE) and try to encapsulate this code. Just a suggestion. Good luck with your project

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is `for` loop. Let me demonstrate with your code:

```
var count = 10; //number of times to run the for loop
for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * myImages1.length);
        if (rnd == 0) {
            rnd = 1;
        }

    document.getElementById("gen-img").src = myImages1[rnd];
}
```

The above code would run the randomizing bit 10 times (= 10 images). Now, I have not tested it yet, but I believe that the images would flash by really quickly. Also, unrelated to the question you may want to read about Javascript [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for your reply, I do believe you're correct but sadly the output doesn't seem to have any effect at all and thus wont load any images, Thank you for trying your hardest and I will try my best to use this. Is there any other possibility or reasons why it might not work?

Comment: do you ever actually call the `imgRandom()` function? None of that code will execute unless you call that function.